# Spring MVC verification email sending service

Tags: java, unit-testing, email

I have a `@Service` to send verification emails. Here is the code of the service:

```
package my.package.service.impl;

//imports

@Service
public class EmailSenderServiceImpl implements EmailSenderService {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( EmailSenderServiceImpl.class );

    @Autowired
    EmailVerificationTokenService emailVerificationService;

    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;

    @Override
    public boolean sendVerificationEmail( final String appUrl, final Locale locale, final UserDto user ) {
        final String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        emailVerificationService.insertToken( user.getIdUser(), token );

        final String body = createEmailBody( appUrl, locale, user, token );

        final String to = user.getEmail();

        final String subject = MessageResourceUtility.getMessage( "e.verify.email.subject", null, locale );

        return sendEmail( body, to, subject );
    }

    private boolean sendEmail( final String body, final String to, final String subject ) {
        try {
            if( emailService.sendEmail( to, subject, body ) ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                LOGGER.debug( "Email NOT sent" );
                return false;
            }
        } catch( final MessagingException e ) {
            LOGGER.error( "Error sending email" );
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String createEmailBody( String appUrl, final Locale locale, final UserDto user, final String token ) {
        appUrl = appUrl.substring( 0, appUrl.lastIndexOf( "/" ) );
        appUrl += "/accountVerification?token=" + token;
        appUrl += "&username=" + user.getUserName();

        final Object[] array = new Object[] { user.getName(), user.getSurname(), appUrl };

        final String body = MessageResourceUtility.getMessage( "e.verify.email", array, locale );
        return body;
    }
}
```

And here is the test class:

```
package my.package.app.service;

//imports

@RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PrepareForTest( MessageResourceUtility.class )
public class EmailSenderServiceTest {

    private static final String URL = "https://www.ysi.si/register/";

    @InjectMocks
    EmailSenderService emailSenderService = new EmailSenderServiceImpl();

    @Mock
    EmailService emailService;

    @Mock
    EmailVerificationTokenService emailVerificationTokenService;

    Locale locale;

    UserDto user;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
        user = new UserDto();

        when( emailService.sendEmail( Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString() ) ).thenReturn( true );
        mockStatic( MessageResourceUtility.class );
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateValidationToken() throws Exception {
        emailSenderService.sendVerificationEmail( URL, locale, user );

        verify( emailVerificationTokenService, times( 1 ) ).insertToken( Matchers.anyInt(), Matchers.anyString() );
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnFalseWhenError() throws Exception {
        when( emailService.sendEmail( Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString() ) ).thenThrow( new MessagingException() );

        final boolean returnValue = emailSenderService.sendVerificationEmail( URL, locale, user );

        assertEquals( "Returns false when error", false, returnValue );
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnFalseWhenEmailNotSent() throws Exception {
        when( emailService.sendEmail( Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString() ) ).thenReturn( false );

        final boolean returnValue = emailSenderService.sendVerificationEmail( URL, locale, user );

        assertEquals( "Returns false when email not sent", false, returnValue );
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSendAnEmailWithTheToken() throws Exception {
        final boolean returnValue = emailSenderService.sendVerificationEmail( URL, locale, user );

        verify( emailService, times( 1 ) ).sendEmail( Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyString() );
        assertEquals( "Returns true when success", true, returnValue );
    }

}
```

I have the feeling I am not unit testing in the proper way. I feel like the test code is too coupled to production code. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code!

As far as I see you're running your tests through the *public interface* of the class under test and you verify its results and the communication with its dependencies. That exactly like it should be.

There are just a few issues:

## avoid PowerMock

IMHO having to use PowerMock(-ito) is a surrender to bad design. In your case the Problem is the `MessageResourceUtility` cause the problem.

There is no such rule as that classes providing utility methods must declare them  static.

## avoid verify with `any*` matchers

Test cases should be as explicit as possible. That means that you should verify the parameters of the methods called against *concrete values* by any chance.

Eg. you could verfy that the ID given by the user is passed to the dependency by the cut. Cause here is similar as above: The dependency to `UUID` class is hidden by the static access. Problem here is that UUID is provided by the JVM so that you cannot simply convert it to an "instance-able" utility class. You should encapsulate that in a facade class which you can pass in as dependency.